# DHCP Client Identifier vs mac addr which comes first

Tags: server, client-server, mac-address, dhcp

If the client identifier is changed in a device should the server lease a new ip address or use the existing lease which is bound to the mac address and the old client identifier?

I.e. Should the mac address be used as the first alternative regardless of the change in Client Identifier and give the same address?